# picketlink, envers and cdi injection

Tags: cdi, hibernate-envers

I am using picketlink to authenticate a user on project. I also created a @produces annotated method, so I would be able to inject the authenticated user in other places. Now, I am using envers and besides the default information, I would like to store the user that performed the action, but I cannot inject it in the envers listener. It is always null. How can I make this injection, or retrieve this information?

The producer class:

```
@SessionScoped
public class Resources implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private AuthenticationManagerBean authenticator;

    @Inject
    private Identity credentials;

    @CurrentUser
    private AuthenticatedUser currentUser;

    @Produces
    @CurrentUser
    @SessionScoped
    private AuthenticatedUser createAuthenticatedUser() {
        AuthenticatedUser user = new AuthenticatedUser();
        org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User loggedInUser = (org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.User) credentials.getAccount();

        User pu = authenticator.getUserRoles(loggedInUser.getLoginName());

        if (pu != null) {
            user.setUser(pu.getName());

            for (Role role : pu.getRoles()) {
                user.getRoles().add(role.getName());
            }
        }

        return user;
    }

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }
```

and the envers listener:

```
public class AuditListener implements RevisionListener, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    @CurrentUser
    private AuthenticatedUser identity; //this is always null

    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {

        System.out.println(identity.getUser());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similiar problem. The injection does not work because RevisionListener is not managed by CDI. That way, you have to lookup for the bean yourself. This is the way you could do it:

```
public AuthenticatedUser getAuthenticatedUser() {
    BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    Bean<AuthenticatedUser> bean = (Bean<AuthenticatedUser>) beanManager.getBeans(AuthenticatedUser.class, new AnnotationLiteral<CurrentUser>() {
    }).iterator().next();

    CreationalContext<AuthenticatedUser> ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
    return (AuthenticatedUser) beanManager.getReference(bean, AuthenticatedUser.class, ctx);
}
```